# How can I match a corresponding cell value based on a key word using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that web scrapes data and returns the results to to a separate worksheet. These results however, have to be processed so the all titles are extracted in one column in the "Search results" section. I can't figure out how to write a function that will return all values associated with the term "TI". I have written some code but it doesn't work. Any help or suggestions regarding this would be appreciated.

[Search results worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7knAq.png)

[Raw data worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbnL8.png)

Sub Returnresults()

```
 Dim r As Range

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 With Worksheets("Search Results")
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=TI"
With .AutoFilter.Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 
    2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        r.Copy Worksheets("Search Results").Range("A7")
    End If
End With
.AutoFilterMode = False
 End With

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

Comment: what _"doesn't work"_?

Comment: @DisplayName My current code, is there a more efficient way to go about this perhaps?

Comment: so it does work, but it's not efficient?

Comment: @DisplayName No the code is not yielding the results I am looking for, any suggestions for this type of task would be appreciated.

Comment: give an example of correct result

Comment: Sorry I am new to coding, I am not even sure if I am using the right sub for this purpose. I would like to loop a function to go down column A in the results workbook and retrieve all the values associated with "TI" and return them to the results section. I cannot figure out what syntax to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what should be a working code with minimal deviations (explanations in comments) from yours

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReturnResults()

    Dim r As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' reference results sheet
        If IsEmpty(.Range("A1")) Then .Range("A1").Value = "dummy header" ' if A1 is empty, put a "dummy" header to make AutoFilter work properly

        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Offset(, -1) ' reference referenced sheet column A range from row 1 down to column B last not empty cell
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=R[-1]C" ' fill referenced range blank cells with the same value as the not empty cell above
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=TI"
            On Error Resume Next
            Set r = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Copy Worksheets("Search Results").Range("B7")
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).ClearContents ' clear cell with formulas
            If .Range("A1").Value = "dummy header" Then .Range("A1").ClearContents ' remove any "dummy" header
        End With
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm, you are a life saver :)